# Is there a way to modify a datatable, like filter the information?

Tags: php, datatable, datatables, doctrine, symfony-2.8

Actually I have a html.twig file in which I have the next datatable:

--------------------------------------
Audits       |          Areas   
--------------------------------------
     1         |         Area1
     2         |         Area1
     3         |         Area1
     4         |         Area1
     5         |         Area2
     6         |         Area2
     7         |         Area2
     8         |         Area2
--------------------------------------

[Screen shot of the Current Datatable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0HHg5.png)

But I what want to do is to show the datatable in this way:
--------------------------------------
Audits       |          Areas   
--------------------------------------
1, 2, 3, 4  |         Area1
5, 6, 7, 8  |         Area2
--------------------------------------

This is how I get the info in my **controller**:

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();

        $auditsByAuditor = $em->getRepository('FSABundle:FsaAudits')
                            ->findBy(array('idAuditor'=>$auditor->getId()));


        return $this->render('FSABundle:FsaAudits:FsaPlan.html.twig', array(
            'currentPlan' => $currentPlan,
            'auditsByAuditor' => $auditsByAuditor
        ));
```

This is how I have the **html.twig:**

```
<div class="table-responsive">
                <br/>
                {% for message in app.session.flashbag().get('status') %}
                    <div class="alert alert-success">{{message}}</div>
                    {%endfor%}
                    <table aria-describedby="dataTable_info" cellspacing="0" class="table table-hover dataTable" id="dataTable" role="grid" style="width:100%;" width="100%">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Auditorias</th>
                                <th>Areas</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            {% for audit in auditsByAuditor %}
                                <tr>
                                    <td>{{ audit.idAudit }}</td>
                                    <td>{{ audit.idArea}}</td>
                                </tr>
                            {% endfor %}
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
```

**Any idea or advice about how to make it?**

Comment: `GROUP_CONCAT` by Audits and `GROUP BY` Areas

Comment: I don't know how you will do it, but `select group_concat(Audits) audits, Areas from your table group by Areas` should do the trick. Just see how you map this query in your syntax.

Comment: you need GROUP_CONCAT so concat the audits of a particular area

Comment: sorry, how use it with doctrine?